# Vim setting for a particular extension

Tags: vim

Vim allows us to set particular command for specific type in a `<type>.vim` file config.

However, I could I do for a specific *extension*. I explain: both `.dtx` and `.tex` are extension for (La)TeX. But the first one is for development, so I would like to have a `set spelllang=en`, while the other one is for writing, so I would like to have a `set spelllan=fr`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with [autocommands](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_40.html#40.3) in your vimrc:

```
augroup SpellTeX
  au!
  au BufNewFile,BufRead *.dtx  setl spelllang=en
  au BufNewFile,BufRead *.tex  setl spelllang=fr
augroup END
```

Comment: Thanks, it works nice. However, I have also tried to do it with command, and that does not work

Comment: augroup SpellTeX
 au!
 au BufNewFile,BufRead *.tex command Plan Voom latex
 au BufNewFile,BufRead *.dtx command Plan Voom dtx
augroup END

Comment: Define 'with command' and 'does not work'. You need to include `|` to separate commands if you're typing that on the command line.

Comment: E.g. `:au group SpellTex | au! | ...`

Comment: sorry, I don't understand exactly what should I type.